# How to remove duplicates with the same 'title' field from object list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have class with field `title`. I have also list of objects, but with duplicates.

```
for i in self.qList:
    print(i.title)
```

gives:

```
    War
    Law
    Mummy
    War
    War
```

I want to remove `War` from the list, leaving only one.

I tried this:

```
newlist=[]
for i in self.qList:
    if i.title not in self.qList.title
         newlist.append(i)
```

but got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Comment: @mantazer it's not just the `title` in `qList`/`newlist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is keep a `set` of just the titles, and check against that:

```
newlist = []
titles = set()
for i in self.qList:
    if i.title not in titles:
         newlist.append(i)
         titles.add(i.title)
```

Your code might be easier to read with better variable names, too; what is `qList`, or `i`?

---

If you want to go the list comprehension route, you can do something sneaky with lazy `and` evaluation:

```
titles = set()
newlist = [i for i in self.qList if i.title not in titles and titles.add(i.title) is None]
```

I will leave you to puzzle out exactly how this works!

Comment: Thanks! I have to learn more about comprehension, looks so nerdy ;)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a list comprehension to me.

```
newlist = set(i.title for i in self.qList)
```

if you really wanted  a list then just "cast" it back (ok it's not really casting in python but it looks like it)

```
newlist = list(set(i.title for i in self.qList))
```

Also, a minor added plus of using a generator expression is that there is no "leftover" i variable that you didn't really need for anything.

**EDIT:**
the above incorrect solution is left as a reminder to myself to read the question first.
The "generator based solution" to give the objects would look more like:

```
new_set = set(i.title for i in self.qList)
new_list = [i for i in self.qList if i.title in new_set]
```

I suspect that python's optimization of the generator and list comprehension could still make this faster than the loop but accessing the `i.title` attribute twice is the tradeoff.

I still kind of like it as looking more "pythonic" (performance question pending...)

Comment: This just gets you the titles, *not* the objects with the `title` attribute

Comment: @jonrsharpe doh.  You you are right....+1 for reading the question...I'll try that next time.

Comment: No problem. The list comprehension approach is good - note that you can also iterate over `qList` only once if you are sneaky, see the end of my answer.